# Editing Ubuntu one notes in Safari browser

Tags: ubuntu-one

Yesterday I borrowed a friend's IPad to edit an Ubuntu-One note using the web interface. I found that I couldn't edit the text of a note, only the title. The contents of existing notes were rendered in a kind of "text box", however Safari did not allow me to edit any of the text. This was the same when trying to create a new note.

Is this a Safari problem or something to do with the https://one.ubuntu.com/notes/ ?

Can anyone else replicate? As I was only borrowing the IPad I didn't have time to get enough details (e.g. browser version) in order to submit a decent bug report.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's Safari.

As far as I know, no mobile browser implements the things needed for that page to work. I don't really know why.